# Changing to a new page, still showing errors of unfilled form for half a second

Tags: asp.net, .net

I am still learning ASP.NET for a school project. I have a page with 2 fieldsets on it. One is filled with a log in form (self made, I don't use the asp login control) and the other is filled with a button to go to the register page. The button works and you get redirected to the register page but it shows the error messages of the unfilled login form for half a sec before it links through. I was wondering if there is a way I can stop this from happening. This is the code I have, I don't have added anything to the code behind so I won't post that.

```
<%-- Begin fieldset --%>
    <fieldset>
                    <legend>Log in Form</legend>
                    <ol>

                        <li>
                            <%-- Email label, textbox en validator --%>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Email">Email: </asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Email" TextMode="Email" />
                            <%-- Validator om te zien of het veld is ingevuld --%>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Email"
                                CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="Email is een verplicht veld!" />
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidatorEmail" runat="server" 
                                ControlToValidate="Email" CssClass="field-validation-error" Display="Dynamic" 
                                ValidationExpression="^((?>[a-zA-Z\d!#$%&'*+\-/=?^_`{|}~]+\x20*|((?=[\x01-\x7f])[^\\]|\\[\x01-\x7f])*\x20*)*(?<angle><))?((?!\.)(?>\.?[a-zA-Z\d!#$%&'*+\-/=?^_`{|}~]+)+|((?=[\x01-\x7f])[^\\]|\\[\x01-\x7f])*)@(((?!-)[a-zA-Z\d\-]+(?<!-)\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}|\[(((?(?<!\[)\.)(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d?\d)){4}|[a-zA-Z\d\-]*[a-zA-Z\d]:((?=[\x01-\x7f])[^\\\[\]]|\\[\x01-\x7f])+)\])(?(angle)>)$"
                                ErrorMessage="Gebruik geen illegale tekens in uw email aub!"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <%-- Passwoord label en textbox --%>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password">Wachtwoord: </asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Password" TextMode="Password" />
                            <%-- Validator om te zien of het veld is ingevuld--%>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password"
                                CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="Wachtwoord is een verplicht veld!" />
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                    <%-- Registreer button --%>
                    <asp:Button ID="buttonLogIn" runat="server" CommandName="MoveNext" Text="Log in" />
    </fieldset>
    <%-- Einde fieldset --%>

    <%-- Begin fieldset --%>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Registreer hier!</legend>
            <%-- Registreer button --%>
            <asp:Button ID="buttonRegistreerHier" runat="server" CommandName="MoveNext" Text="Registreer hier!!" 
                OnClick="buttonRegistreerHier_Click" OnClientClick="window.location.href='RegistratieForm.aspx'" 
                PostBackUrl="~/RegistratieForm.aspx" />
    </fieldset>
    <%-- Einde fieldset --%>
```

this is the image of the moment I clicked the button and the error messages get shown, it takes only half a sec to 1 sec but it is bothersome.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is the `CausesValidation` property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.causesvalidation.aspx

> You can specify or determine whether validation is performed on both
>   the client and the server when a Button control is clicked by using
>   the CausesValidation property. To prevent validation from being
>   performed, set the CausesValidation property to false.

```
<asp:Button 
    ID="buttonLogIn" 
    runat="server" 
    CommandName="MoveNext" 
    Text="Log in" 
    CausesValidation="false" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the "Register" button to a hyperlink.

```
<a href="~/RegistratieForm.aspx">Registreer</a>
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks it worked like a charm :) I will select it as answer but I have to 4 minutes or so :)

Comment: This is fine as long as the server side event isn't doing anything more than a redirect. If it is logging or anything like that then it will stop doing that. :)